# base64_* functions disabled, what to do now?

Tags: php, base64, decode, encode

I am getting following warning when I try to use base64_decode() function

```
"Warning: base64_decode() has been disabled for security reasons"
```

Looks like my host has disabled base64_* functions.

I have few questions

1. I think base64_* functions can be enabled by default in php, correct?
2. Is there any security reason why base64_* functions are not enabled? Any security breach?
3. Alternative to base64_* functions, which are available by default?
4. Where can I find custom class/functions for base64_* implementation, so that I can have them in my PHP file, and use them if PHP's base64_* functions are not available?

Help appreciated.

Comment: allot of nasty scripts are base_64 encoded into eval functions. If you really need it, change host

Comment: If your host believes in "security by paranoia"... CHANGE HOSTS.

Comment: is their spy software not base64 compatible? :)

Comment: @Hajo: They're probably assuming that all use of base64_decode is related to obfuscated code. This is, of course, dead wrong.

Comment: Using info from [here](http://www.garykessler.net/library/base64.html), I hacked up a crappy base32 library in PHP (https://github.com/NTICompass/PHP-Base32). I'm sure it wouldn't be too hard to make that do base64 too. I'm at work now but, if I'm bored after work, I can try to add base64 to it.

Answer (score 9):

I have written alternative functions for all base64 purposes.

Look here:

```
function base64_decode($input) {
    $keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
    $chr1 = $chr2 = $chr3 = "";
    $enc1 = $enc2 = $enc3 = $enc4 = "";
    $i = 0;
    $output = "";

    // remove all characters that are not A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, /, or =
    $filter = $input;
    $input = preg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]", "", $input);
    if ($filter != $input) {
        return false;
    }

    do {
        $enc1 = strpos($keyStr, substr($input, $i++, 1));
        $enc2 = strpos($keyStr, substr($input, $i++, 1));
        $enc3 = strpos($keyStr, substr($input, $i++, 1));
        $enc4 = strpos($keyStr, substr($input, $i++, 1));
        $chr1 = ($enc1 << 2) | ($enc2 >> 4);
        $chr2 = (($enc2 & 15) << 4) | ($enc3 >> 2);
        $chr3 = (($enc3 & 3) << 6) | $enc4;
        $output = $output . chr((int) $chr1);
        if ($enc3 != 64) {
            $output = $output . chr((int) $chr2);
        }
        if ($enc4 != 64) {
            $output = $output . chr((int) $chr3);
        }
        $chr1 = $chr2 = $chr3 = "";
        $enc1 = $enc2 = $enc3 = $enc4 = "";
    } while ($i < strlen($input));
    return urldecode($output);
}

function base64_encode($data) {
    $b64 = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';
    $o1 = $o2 = $o3 = $h1 = $h2 = $h3 = $h4 = $bits = $i = 0;
    $ac = 0;
    $enc = '';
    $tmp_arr = array();
    if (!$data) {
        return data;
    }
    do {
    // pack three octets into four hexets
    $o1 = charCodeAt($data, $i++);
    $o2 = charCodeAt($data, $i++);
    $o3 = charCodeAt($data, $i++);
    $bits = $o1 << 16 | $o2 << 8 | $o3;
    $h1 = $bits >> 18 & 0x3f;
    $h2 = $bits >> 12 & 0x3f;
    $h3 = $bits >> 6 & 0x3f;
    $h4 = $bits & 0x3f;
    // use hexets to index into b64, and append result to encoded string
    $tmp_arr[$ac++] = charAt($b64, $h1).charAt($b64, $h2).charAt($b64, $h3).charAt($b64, $h4);
    } while ($i < strlen($data));
    $enc = implode($tmp_arr, '');
    $r = (strlen($data) % 3);
    return ($r ? substr($enc, 0, ($r - 3)) . substr('===', $r) : $enc);
}

function charCodeAt($data, $char) {
    return ord(substr($data, $char, 1));
}

function charAt($data, $char) {
    return substr($data, $char, 1);
}
```

But don't forget the `charCodeAt` and the `charAt` function. They are both necessary for `base64_encode`. 
The two functions `base64_encode` and `base64_decode` both are working like the inbuilt PHP functions. But only use them, if the inbuilt ones are not availible because they're not as fast as the inbuilt ones.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I love you! This is the answer you want to find in a emergency where is no time to code =P

Comment: Thanks @Ivan Shatsky `return ($r ? substr($enc, 0, ($r - 3)) . substr('===', $r) : $enc);`

Comment: If you need to mimic the exact behavior of _base64_decode_, as I do, you must "`Returns FALSE if input contains character from outside the base64 alphabet.`" (as [PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php#refsect1-function.base64-decode-parameters) says). In order to do that, I changed the $input name to $filter (preserving original value of the parameter) and then I added the line: `if($filter!=$input) return false;`.

Comment: @Leopoldo Sanczyk Thanks! Added it.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot.  This is amazing.  Actually this makes was very helpfull for other functions.

Answer (score 1):

Just registered to comment jankal's answer, but can't do it without reputation.

Last line of function base64_encode code in jankal's answer is

```
return ($r ? substr($enc, 0, ($r - 3)) : $enc) . substr('===', ($r || 3));
```

where $r can be 0, 1 or 2. As I understand, ($r || 3) expression value by code logic must be 3 when $r = 0, and $r in other two cases, but in practice (PHP 5.6/7.0) value of this expression always equals to 1, so our BASE64-encoded string always ends with two '=' symbols, which is definitely wrong.

My solution:

```
return ($r ? substr($enc, 0, ($r - 3)) . substr('===', $r) : $enc);
```

Comment: Am I allowed to use your changes in my answer when editing?

Comment: I just did it... if any complaints: please comment or send me a message.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myencode($input)
    {
    $CODES = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

    // the result/encoded string, the padding string, and the pad count
    $r = "";
    $p= "";
    $c = strlen($input) % 3;

    // add a right zero pad to make this string a multiple of 3 characters
    if ($c > 0) 
    {
        for (; $c < 3; $c++)
     {
        $p .= "=";
        $input .= "\0";
     }
    }

    // increment over the length of the string, three characters at a time
    for ($c = 0; $c < strlen($input); $c += 3) {

// we add newlines after every 76 output characters, according to the MIME specs

        if ($c > 0 && ($c / 3 * 4) % 76 == 0)
        $r += "\r\n";

// these three 8-bit (ASCII) characters become one 24-bit number
$n = (ord($input[$c]) << 16) + (ord($input[$c +1]) << 8) + (ord($input[$c +2]));


        // this 24-bit number gets separated into four 6-bit numbers
        $n1 = $n >> 18 & 63;
        $n2 = $n >> 12 & 63;
        $n3 = $n >> 6 & 63;
        $n4 = $n & 63;

 // those four 6-bit numbers are used as indices into the base64 character list

 $r .= "" . $CODES[$n1] . $CODES[$n2] . $CODES[$n3] . $CODES[$n4];

    }
    return substr($r,0,(strlen($r)-strlen($p))) . $p;
    }  



 function mydecode($input) {

 $CODES = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

// remove/ignore any characters not in the base64 characters list
    // or the pad character -- particularly newlines

    $input= str_replace("[^" . $CODES . "=]","",$input);

    // replace any incoming padding with a zero pad (the 'A' character is  zero)
    $p = ($input[strlen($input) - 1] == '=' ?($input[strlen($input) - 2] == '=' ? "AA" : "A") : "");

    $r = "";
    $input = substr($input,0,(strlen($input) - strlen($p))) . $p;
// increment over the length of this encoded string, four characters at a time
    for ($c = 0; $c < strlen($input); $c += 4) {

// each of these four characters represents a 6-bit index in the
// base64 characters list which, when concatenated, will give the
// 24-bit number for the original 3 characters

         $n=(strpos($CODES,$input[$c]) << 18)
         +  (strpos($CODES,$input[$c+1]) << 12)
         +  (strpos($CODES,$input[$c+2]) << 6)
         +  (strpos($CODES,$input[$c+3]));


// split the 24-bit number into the original three 8-bit (ASCII) characters
$r .= "" . chr(($n >> 16) & 0xFF) . chr((($n >> 8) & 0xFF)) . chr(($n & 0xFF));

    }
    // remove any zero pad that was added to make this a multiple of 24 bits
        return substr($r,0, strlen($r)- strlen($p));
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

This is hosting problem.

Please Change your Hosting or ask them to remove this security issue